# SQL Server Reporting Services Table expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Is it possible to use the result of an expression in an expression in another field in a table in SSRS?  For example I have a table with 3 rows of data, then have a total row beneath.  I would then like to point an expression used in another field of the table to use the result of the sum.  Can't figure out how to do it besides recreating the expression calculating the sum within the new expression.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the query or at least pseudo-query?  You can also use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I am not querying SQL, this is for SSRS.  I have a dataset that is being used in a table object on a report.  In the total row I have an expression that sums the value of three fields.  I then want to use this value in the expression in a new field instead of recreating the sum expression.  The closes proxy to this would be using activecell.offset(x,x).value in excel.  What I want is to point the expression of one field in the table to the value of another field in the table.

Comment: so here is the example to hopefully clarify.  i have 2 fields next to each other in a table, one showing minutes and the other hours.

the expression in the minute field is this:
=Fields!TotalTimeMin.Value-Fields!LunchMin.Value-Fields!BreakMin.Value-(Fields!TotalTimeMin.Value*Fields!VacationPct.Value)

instead of duplicating this string and adding /60 in the hour field i was hoping to just be able to put 'minute field'.value/60 in the expression of the hour filed.

hope that clears it up.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `ReportItems` collection with the name of the textbox containing the first total, like:

```
=ReportItems!MyTextboxName.Value / 60
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I knew there had to be a way to do it.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which will hold calculation logic. Pass the database fields to the function and function will return you the results of calculation. You can call the function again and anywhere you want in the report. I hope this helps.